# Angular: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a third party component rendered from node modules in my Appcomponent. I want do display a paragraph inside that third party component.

app.component.html

```
<div id="dashboard" class="content-fluid aui standalone">
  <cs-sidebar [nav]="navigation" class="candisableNav">
  </cs-sidebar>
</div>
```

Component

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.rd); 
    console.log(this.el); 
    let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-header__title')
    console.log(elem)
    let a = document.createElement('p');
    console.log(a)
    a.innerHTML = 'Version 0.5';
    console.log(elem.item(0))
    elem.item(1).appendChild(a);
}
```

In ngAfterViewInit() of AppComponent I'm trying append a p tag into the CsSideBarcomponent. elem = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-header__title') is fectching the div tag and I'm able to see in the console. But I'm getting "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined" error for elem.item(1).appendChild(a). I'm pushing to the index 1 as there is already an element at 0th index which I need it. I saw the posts over here and I'm doing in the same way. Any help please

Comment: are you sure you have a `sidebar-header__title` class element in your html file ?

Comment: @Abra001 Yes I'm able to console it

Comment: `elem.item(1)` is undefined

Comment: try rather to console `elem[1]` and see.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz What could be the issue

Comment: @Abra001 I tried no luck

Comment: what do you mean by no luck ? if it prints out `undefined` there should be something with your dom tree.

Comment: @Abra001 If I console.log(elem.item[0]) I can see the 0th element. elem.item[1].appendChild(a); is throwing appendChild null error

Comment: why do you append child to an undefined element i can't understand your logic tbh.